# The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint, cascading delete

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete a user form 'dbo.Gebruiker' when I run my query I get this error message.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Klant_Gebruiker_beheerderid". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Planning", table "dbo.Klant", column 'BeheerderId'.

After reading on the forum, they said that first I have to remove from other table so when I run my query, again I get another message

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Gebruiker_Klant". The conflict occurred in database "Planning",
>   table "dbo.Gebruiker", column 'KlantId'.

When I run this query to see if that columns exists

> select * from dbo.Gebruiker where
>   KlantId='1CA25570-1A02-42FC-836D-4897B95EF44A'

it does not show anything.

After reading on google and on forums they say that first I have to delete the foreign key constraint.

I'm also putting the **helpConstraint**

[image]

[image]

What would be best way to delete a user from "dbo.Gebruiker" please?

GebruikerTable and Dependencies
KlantTable and Dependencies

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you have *circular* references. Without seeing the table definitions, nor having any sample data, nor knowing what actual `delete` statements you've run that provoke these errors, it's difficult to be sure though. If you have circular references you'll first have to `UPDATE` one of the tables so that it's no longer referencing the row from the other table that you're trying to delete from.

Comment: I.e. if google translate is working for me, you appear to have a `Customers` table and a `Users` table. All `Users` belong to a `Customer` and each `Customer` has one special `User` identified as the `Administrator`. You cannot remove a row from the `Users` table if *that user is the current administrator for **a** customer*. If you've not built your integrity correctly, it's perfectly possible that *the administrator is not constrained to be a user for that customer*.

Comment: Can a `Gebruiker` be a `Beheerder`? Can you show us the data in the `Gebruiker` table you're trying to remove?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes you are absolutely right as google translate did.

Comment: @SchmitzIT I have put more images

Comment: @user2983359 I see the same images as before.

Comment: @SchmitzIT check it now please

Comment: The last image you added shows a foreign key relationship on the `BeheerderId`. What table / column does that point to? (Hopefully it points to `GebruikerId` in table `Gebruiker`.

If so, what does the following query show you? `select beheerderId` from dbo.Klant where KlantId='1CA25570-1A02-42FC-836D-4897B95EF44A'`.
Then use that BeheerderID and run this: `SELECT GebruikerID, KlantID FROM dbo.Gebruiker WHERE GebruikerID = <%beheerderid%>`. Replace <%beheerderid%> with the value you found before.

Comment: @SchmitzIT when I run this query 
select beheerderId from dbo.Klant where KlantId='1CA25570-1A02-42FC-836D-4897B95EF44A'

It does not show anything. Empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169752/discussion-between-user2983359-and-schmitzit).

Comment: @SchmitzIT sorry I made a mistake now I have the value of GebruikerID and KlantID, 
GebruikerID 
1CA25570-1A02-42FC-836D-4897B95EF44A
KlantID
069AFB05-5C31-452F-9563-4A148BFC294C

Comment: I'm in the chat, but at work, so might not answer straight away

Answer (score 0):

In general terms, if you want to delete a row whose id is a FK in another table and you are not using an automated DELETE rule (like CASCADE), then you need to do something with the rows on the dependent table(s) before the database will allow you to perform the DELETE.

It seems that this your problem, so you need to consider what to do with the rows of the dependent table(s) that currently refer to the key value of the row you intend to delete.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. My db is in circular reference form. Any idea how to do it carefully ?